# Changing bar and background colours using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the colour bars using ggplot2 on a bar graph with frequency data. However, my plot is still appearing in greyscale.

Data (400 observations that take values between 1 to 5) and code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

# Sample data
complete_data <- data.frame(education = sample(1:5, 400, replace = TRUE)) 

ggplot(complete_data, aes(x=education)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="count") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("1" = "Level 1", "2" = "Level 2","3" = "Level 3","4" = "Level 4")) +
  geom_point(aes(color = education)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PuBu")
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Error in `check_required_aesthetics()`:
> ! geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: y
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

What am I doing wrong?
I also want to make the background white but that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Are you trying to plot both bars *and* points? Note that the color= scale and fill= scale are two different scales.

Comment: Only bars. I just want the frequency of each level of education (1-5). Edited the question to add a sample of data.

Comment: as @MrFlick said, data to reproduce the problem would help allot. General tips: ```geom_point``` is used to make scatterplots, so it will need a x and y coordinate. If you want to make the background white, consider using ```theme_bw()``` between your ggplot() and geom_bar().

Comment: You should **never** use `attach()`. It creates problems. Like here, when you do `edu <- as.factor(edu)`, that modifies an object named `edu`, but if you look at the class of the column in your `data`, `class(data$edu)`, it hasn't changed. ggplot is looking in your data, so it doesn't know about the `factor` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can remove the `geom_point` because that is used for scatterplots. You can use the `scale_fill_brewer` if you use `fill` in your aesthetics of your `ggplot`. You change the background with `theme` and `panel.background` like this:

```r
complete_data <- read.table(text = "      education
         1
         2
         1
         3
         3
         4", header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.1.2
library(RColorBrewer)
#> Warning: package 'RColorBrewer' was built under R version 4.1.2

complete_data$education <- as.character(complete_data$education)

ggplot(complete_data, aes(x=education, fill = education)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("1" = "Level 1", "2" = "Level 2","3" = "Level 3","4" = "Level 4")) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PuBu") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>